# Finding value of x in logarithms?

Tags: logarithms

> Q) Find the value of $x$ in $2 \log x + \log 5 = 2.69897$

So far I got:
$$2 \log x + \log 5 = 2.69897$$
$$\Rightarrow \log x^2 + \log 5 = 2.69897 $$

$$\Rightarrow \log 5x^2 = 2.69897 $$

What should I do next?

<sub>Note: In this question $\log(x) \implies \log_{10}(x)$ , it is therefore implied to use $\ln(x)$ to denote natural logarithm</sub>

Comment: $$\log_{10}(500)=2.69897000434$$

Comment: @lab: Sure, but who would have known that without a calculator.

Comment: @Nick, I think, she has missed to include this information to the Question

Comment: @lab: Well, I think it's good challenge to solve this question as it is given without a calculator or log table.

Comment: Making quadratic equation from linear... Definitely worth it!

Comment: @sas: Are you being sarcastic or did you mean that it's easier to do it the she's done it?

Comment: @Nick, I'm being sarcastic. But now you can ask if I'm being sarcastic right now. No, I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, if $a^x=b$, then $\log_a(b)=x$
$$\log_{10}(5x^2)=2.69897$$
$$10^{2.69897}=5x^2$$
$$x^2=\dfrac{10^{2.69897}}{5}$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{10^{2.69897}}{5}}$$
We will discard the negative root because we cannot have something like $\log(x)$ where $x < 0$. Therefore:
$$\displaystyle \boxed{x=\sqrt{\dfrac{10^{2.69897}}{5}}}$$

Comment: Do you really want that negative solution?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believe that the negative solution will be made positive when you put it through $5x^2$. If it was $5x^3$ or something I would reject the negative solution

Comment: But what happens when you put it in the original equation, to see whether it is really a solution?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I still get 2.69897, I am not lying.

Comment: @JChau The equation does not contain $x^2$ at all. Still don't understand conversion to quadratic and back. Meaningless.

Comment: @JChau: Remember the original equation the OP had, had the term log(x). You cannot have that negative value of x.

Comment: Oh woops I only read the last equation. Thank you all for pointing out my mistake. It is fixed now.

Comment: @JChau: Your answer requires a calculator to finally get a solution. `sqrt((10^2.69897) / 5) = 9.99999995008`. Wouldn't you say my answer is more elegant?

Comment: @Nick OP did not specify the exact value of the logarithm did he? :P if he really did not approximate the log and has to find what log value will give $2.69897$, my answer is correct. Good observation though

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the OP is using base 10 logs instead of the standard base $e$ log. So, using base 10 logs,

We have that $\log(500) = 2.69897...$ and $\log(100)=2$. Thus,

\begin{align*}
&\quad 2 \log(x) + \log(5) = \log(500) \\
&\implies 2\log(x) = \log(500) - \log(5) \\
&\implies 2\log(x)=\log(100) \\
&\implies 2 \log(x) = 2 \\
&\implies \log(x) = 1 \\
&\implies x = 10^1 \\
&\implies x=10.
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent! The fact that it's log(500) is actually intuitive. It lies between log(100) which is 2 and log(1000) which is 3. So, intuitively log(500) is kinda close to 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Raise the base of the logarithm to both sides. Then, you get $5 x^2 = b^{2.69897}$ where $b$ is the base of the logarithm (probably $b=10$). Then, solve for $x$ by dividing by $5$ and taking square roots.

Comment: I dislike taking roots. What do we do about the negative root? Is it valid?

Comment: Also, how do you compute antilog(2.69897) without a calculator or log table?

Comment: @Nick Taylor series.

Comment: @GammaFunction: I've provided an answer using it. Do you have any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Oh.

$$2 \log_b x + \log_b 5 = 2.69897=a$$
$$\log_b x=(a-\log_b 5)/2$$
$$x=b^{(a-\log_b 5)/2}$$
And after about a half and a hour you may have $$x=\sqrt{b^{a-\log 5}}=\sqrt{b^a/5}$$ and so on

Comment: This is the same answer @JChau has provided.

Answer (score 0):

The [comment given on your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704903/finding-value-of-x-in-logarithms?noredirect=1#comment1476106_704903) is the quickest answer there is.

$\log(5x^2)= \log(500) \implies x=10$

I dislike using a calculator or log table to get the answer. I think such things are supposed to only make lives easier and faster, they should not be the only way to find solutions.

Here's a rough long road just for the sake of independence from machines.
Let us consider using a Taylor expansion to estimate the answer.
I'll give you two simple expansions that you can use to approximate $\ln(x)$:

$$\ln(1-x) = -\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \quad\forall\space \mid x\mid\space < 1$$
$$\ln(1+x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n} \quad\forall\space \mid x\mid\space < 1$$

For convenience, let's roll back to the original equation we had:
$$2 \log(x) + \log(5) = 2.69897 \\ \Rightarrow 2 \log(x) + \log (0.5\times 10) = 2.69897  \\ \Rightarrow 2 \log(x) + \log (0.5) = 1.69897$$

$$\ln(0.5) = \ln(1-0.5) = -\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(0.5)^n}{n} = -(\frac{(0.5)^1}{1} + \frac{0.5^2}{2} + \frac{0.5^3}{3} + \dots) \approx -0.693147$$

But we want $\log(0.5)$, so we need to use the change of base formula,
$$ \log(0.5) = \frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(10)} = \frac{-0.693147}{2.302585} \approx -0.301029$$

You can find $\ln(10)$ using the series I showed you and I advise you to keep that value in memory.

Now,
$$ 2 \log(x) - 0.301029 = 1.69897 \\ 2 \log(x) = 1.69897 + 0.301029 = 1.999999 \approx 2 \\ \log(x) = 1 \\ x = 10^1$$

---

**Some additional points:**

- Sometimes you'll be faced to calculate $\text{anti}\log(x)$, for that here's another series:

$$ 10^x = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n \ln^n(10)}{n!}$$

- If you want faster ways of doing it, then please check out [Euler's acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform) or if you want really heavy guns, then there's the [Cohen-Villegas-Zagier acceleration](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1046889587). But for simple stuff like what we have, [Newton-Raphson](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~anstee/math104/newtonmethod.pdf) is good too.<sub>(Courtesy of Balarka Sen)</sub>
- That intermediate base conversion is kind of a bummer for me and most people but remember that you can be creative during such calculation: $\Large \frac{\ln 0.5}{\ln 10} = - \frac{1}{1 + (\ln 5) / (\ln 2)} \approx \frac{1}{1 + (\ln 4) / ( \ln 2 )} = \frac{1}{3}$ <sub>[(Approximation by N3buchadnezzar)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14185754#14185754)</sub>
- Remembering certain values can help. If you don't want to do all of those approximations, then just remember the first 10 or so prime values of $x$ for $\log(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ but I do strongly recommend you remembering $\ln(10)$ and $\log(e)$ becuase base conversions always require those values.
  By remembering a few values, you can find other values simply using your creativity and knowledge of the logarithmic rules:
  $$ \log(5) = \log(\frac{10}{2}) = \log(10) - \log(2) = 1 - \log(2) \approx 1 - 0.301029 = 0.698971$$